# Are there any soho class wireless routers capable of layer 2 encryption?

Tags: security, wireless-networking, encryption, wireless-access-point

Are there any SOHO class wireless routers that are capable of encryption at layer 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) (even with [L2TP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L2TP)) with [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/). It runs on a large number of SOHO routers. ([List of supported devices.](http://oldwiki.openwrt.org/TableOfHardware.html)) [A short guide about L2TP+IPsec on OpenWRT](http://oldwiki.openwrt.org/L2TP%282b%29IPSEC.html).

But you should know that according to some benchmarks you should only get 3 Mb/s with an average router.

Some routers have hardware assistance for encryption (e.g. the [WRVS4400N](http://www.linksys.com/servlet/Satellite?c=L_Product_C2&childpagename=HU%2FLayout&cid=1175240184111&pagename=Linksys%2FCommon%2FVisitorWrapper&lid=8411169948B01)). If you need performance you should choose one of them.

Comment: Win for Open source routing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some relatively cheap routers like the [WRV54G](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=WRV54G&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=6780358913620279183&ei=PLuJSrTNLZGoMKCXwdYE&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=4#ps-sellers) if you'd like something completely packaged. As Kovbal said, chances are you can  take a current wireless router you have and do the same with OpenWRT/DD-WRT and OpenVPN/etc if that's a route you're interested in.